# android - Displaying time as an image

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I can't find the way displaying time in my timer app.
I've got some nice numbers saved as images in PNG and want to display time using them - animating switching of every second. Something simillar to

### http://thepokerclock.com/app

When I click **+** button near round length numbers are changing with animation. What is the best decision for it? I've thought about 2 ImageSwitchers for seconds and minutes, but it's rather complicated to use.

Comment: You can find good custom fonts on net instead of using images.

Comment: Yeah but can you help - can i animate it in a proper way?
For example i have 16:57, when it changes to 16:56 - can i animate only last char changing?

Comment: I think it can be performed via the use of individual textviews for each digit